# Updating huge database records

Tags: php, mysql

I have 200,000 plus records in mysql database. When I run update query lets say 5000 records it takes ages to perform this task and can not see anything on browser so I am unable to see how much records query has been updated before it finish. Is there any solution available or any help?

Comment: Why is this the tenth nonsense question in the last 15 minutes? Is there a full moon or something?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, It *is* 11/11/11...

Comment: @esqew: Not any more! _[ I accept only the **one true timezone** ]_

Comment: The only day of the year where the US date notation system isn't completely insane

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Why this is first nonsensnse person with such comment I have seen on this website. Question is to be asked. if person is not clear or dont have idea then they ask questions.If you dont know answer you can skip and better to not put you view here. Thanks

Comment: @Adhaata: Thanks for your pointless attempt at reverse psychology. If you take the trouble to take a brief look at my profile, you'll see that I spend a considerable amount of time contributing to this community, and have done for quite a while. Your theory that I should not be able to air my views is, quite frankly, offensive. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I apologise for my comment if you think it was frankly or offensive. I respect your knowledge and contribution however the comment made by you was neither related to solution nor it will encourage people to become part the question. Thanks

Comment: btw kindly post your update statements here so we could take a look and analyze it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not batch these? You can then see progress more easily.

Comment: Hi adam, thanks for answer I was thinking that as well. Do you know or have any idea about any framework I can use for batch?

Comment: It could be as simple as making the query take the TOP X of a select and then performing the update on those records. Then just repeat.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is probably to add indexes to one or more columns, improving the performance of the `UPDATE` query.  Start by running an `EXPLAIN` and likely adding an index to a `CHAR/VARCHAR` column used in the update query's `WHERE` clause.